# Copy directory and its subdirectories & files with a condition

Tags: python

I would like to copy my directory and its subdirectories wih a condition (check a list if its name exist)

My code follows:

```
foo = list()
for folder in os.listdir(directory_path)
     if folder in foo:
       shutil.copy(folder,location_path)
```

I am getting:

```
no such file or directory (Filenotfound) error
```

How can i copy folder with its files with a given condition?

Comment: You need to join the folder name to the directory path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a ':' after your for loop.

But the thing is that the ````folder``` variable is a name of some directory but isnt a path to a directory.

Try adding the `directory_path` to the path:

```python
foo = list()
for folder in os.listdir(directory_path) # directory_path has to end with '/'
     if folder in foo:
       shutil.copy(directory_path + folder,location_path)
```

Comment: sorry for the typo but adding the directory path to the path worked. thank you!

Comment: You should join path elements using os.path.join